# How to use java internal XMLStreamWriter with another provider present

Tags: java, xml, java-7, java-6

I'm using this code to get an `XMLStreamWriter`:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
    .newInstance()
    .createXMLStreamWriter( outputStream )
```

Recently I had to include the jars of `jaxws` to my system. After that the `XmlStreamWriter` implementation changed from `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl` to `com.ctc.wstx.sw.SimpleNsStreamWriter`. This class produces a different output than the java internal implementation.

How can I force java to use the internal implementation without binding my code to java 6 by using `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl` explicitly? Java 7 uses a different `XMLStreamWriter`, and I want my code to run with java 7, too.

---

I tried this:

```
XMLOutputFactory.newFactory( 
    "com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl", 
    getClass().getClassLoader() 
);
```

which is working with Oracle JDK 6, but with JDK 7 it leads to

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: 
Provider for com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl cannot be found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.html#newFactory%28%29) this is how the factory operates:

- Use the javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory system property.
- Use the properties file "lib/stax.properties" in the JRE directory.
- Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification)
- Platform default XMLOutputFactory instance.

So to be sure to use the sun internal implementation, I think the best way is to do the following:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl");
XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

A very old thread of course but I still faced that issue and solved it with JDK 9+ and this line of code:

```
XMLOutputFactory.newDefaultFactory();
```

Maybe this helps someone later on... might be even myself when facing that problem again. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's bad style, but it works for Oracles Java 6 and 7:

```
new com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl( 
    outputStream, 
    encoding, 
    new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.PropertyManager(
        PropertyManager.CONTEXT_WRITER
    ) 
);
```

For being able to compile this I have to call `javac` with the following options:

```
-XDignore.symbol.file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `StaxUtils` from https://java.net/projects/stax-utils/pages/Home,

which has: https://java.net/projects/stax-utils/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/javanet/staxutils/IndentingXMLStreamWriter.java